# Maven: error when adding a dependency to a jar which is inside a .tgz file

Tags: java, build, maven-3, dependency-management

```
Myapp.tgz
        |_ lib
            |_ abc.jar
```

I have a project 'Project1' which needs to have dependency on a jar and this jar is inside a *.tgz file(`Myapp.tgz`).
My requirement is that I need to be able to **import classes in **abc.jar**** from **Project1**.
Myapp.tgz file is inside the maven repository that I am using.(e.g. it is accessbile to maven from http://xxxx.net/artifactory/app-cloud )

The structure of the tgz file is shown above. The tgz file has a folder and the jar that I need to add dependency is inside it.

Through maven plugins, how can I unpack the tgz file and make sure the jar is added as a dependency in pom.xml?

```
    <dependency>
          <groupId>zz.yy.zz</groupId>
          <artifactId>Myapp</artifactId>
          <version>0.1.4.1</version>
          <type>tgz</type>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
      <artifactId>artifactofabcjar</artifactId>
      <groupId>groupidofabcjar</groupId>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${project.build.directory}/classes/Myapp/lib/abc.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
    
<build>
    <plugins>   
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId} unpack-dependencies</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
              <includeTypes>tgz</includeTypes>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>fincore</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <groupId>zz.yy.kk</groupId>
              <artifactId>artname</artifactId>
              <version>0.1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
              <packaging>jar</packaging>
              <file>${project.build.directory}/classes/Myapp/lib</file>
              <createChecksum>true</createChecksum>
              <generatePom>true</generatePom>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
 </plugins>
  </build>
```

I added the above mentioned plugins to pom.xml of 'Project1'. But when I added dependency of abc.jar in pom.xml, it is showing the following error 'Dependency not found'. How to fix this error?
[image]